# How to remove mms sending warnining in cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova, permissions

Cordova app after installing warns me about MMS Sending.
Appears only on Xiaomi RedMi Note3 (MIUI)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vlSb.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can add and remove any permission

navigate to `<project directory>/platforms/Android/` and open `AndroidManifest.xml`

you will all see permissions at last like following

```
...other permissions....
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...other permissions....
```

remove the line the line with MMS's permission in it.

**Beware: Removing the permission added by plugin can cause app crash.**

Comment: i have only these permission there: 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: actually, my problem is called "paid services", that appears right after installing app

Comment: haven't seen that kind of thing in android.
can you update your question and add a screenshot ?